# how to sort data with multiple data sets within a single row?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I sort a mySQL data set based on a certain set that is stored randomly in each row? (i.e., the 'field' I want to sort is like [x-yyyyyyy], where 'x' is the initial number I am looking for, and 'yyyyy' is what I want to sort) **(EDIT: see at very end for the 'mysql' version)**.

I.e., this is my data in a mySQL field (lets say called 'items'):

```
 row 1: [1-283482][3-4848484][6-484868]
 row 2: [6-484444][1-1111][5-4338484]
 row 3: [7-484444][1-9999][3-4338484]
```

I want to "sort" any field that starts with a "[1-", and then sort the 2nd half numerically?

So, for example, if I was sorting ascending, it would give me the results:

```
 row 2: [6-484444][1-1111][5-4338484]
 row 3: [7-484444][1-9999][3-4338484]
 row 1: [1-283482][3-4848484][6-484868]
```

(because removing the '[1-', the order is:

```
 "1111"
 "9999"
 "283482"
```

in terms of numerical values?)

and of course descending would be:

```
  row 1: [1-283482][3-4848484][6-484868]
  row 3: [7-484444][1-9999][3-4338484]
  row 2: [6-484444][1-1111][5-4338484]
```

Thanks very much!

In other words (from a MYSQL perspective), the data looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `testTable` (
   `autoID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `item` text NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 INSERT INTO `testTable` (`autoID`, `item`) VALUES
 (1, '[1-283482][3-4848484][6-484868]'),
 (2, '[6-484444][1-1111][5-4338484]'),
 (3, '[7-484444][1-9999][3-4338484]');

 ALTER TABLE `testTable`
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`autoID`);
```

And I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
 Select `item` from  `testTable` order by '[1-*****]' asc
```

Comment: I am lost.  What does a row look like?  What are the columns?  Are you storing multiple values in a single string column?  That is just a broken data model, so work on fixing the data model first.

Comment: it is sets of data. let me edit the question to put it into a 'mysql' format.

Comment: kk, I've added the mySQL at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the rows contain this substring `'[1-'` in the column `item` then this should do:

```
select * from testTable
order by substring(item, locate('[1-', item) + 3) + 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qmAPcDufJbPYKrtswVdao8/0).
Results:

```
| autoID | item                            |
| ------ | ------------------------------- |
| 2      | [6-484444][1-1111][5-4338484]   |
| 3      | [7-484444][1-9999][3-4338484]   |
| 1      | [1-283482][3-4848484][6-484868] |
```

If there are also other rows that do not contain `'[1-'` and you want these rows at the end:

```
select * from testTable
order by item not like '%[1-%',
         substring(item, locate('[1-', item) + 3) + 0
```

Comment: fantastic, thanks! this works, & exactly what I needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function `substring` of mysql for get the number on right

Example:

```
SELECT string,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX('[1-283482][3-4848484][6-484868]','][',1),'[',''),'-',-1),SIGNED) as num from table
ORDER BY num desc
```

other option is whit `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

```
SELECT item,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item,'][',1),'[',''),'-',-1),SIGNED) as num from testTable
    ORDER BY num desc
```

Comment: okay -  don't quite get where I would specify the "[1-" field here - thought it would be replacing 'string'? could you please post specifically for that? (tried this, and it didn't seem to work), thanks!

Comment: okay, I cut & paste it exactly (using that testtable + data), and I get this error message: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'

Comment: change REMPLACE for  REPLACE

Comment: change INTEGER for SIGNED, i think this fail

Comment: thx for your help, doesn't quite seem to give the correct results, although it seems to be the 'right' idea...